# Case in SQL join not stopping at first successful match

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

I'm currently working with a B2B sales database that doesn't have a unique identifier for each customer. New records are allocated an ID code when loaded but the a person can have more than one ID code for various reasons.

The business regularly runs events where they capture registration data. I'm trying to match the event data (pre DB load) to a table of existing contacts. This is proving challenging as nothing is unique (not even email addresses as they can be shared or associated with multiple records in the contacts master table).

I need to run some code to flag where new contacts exist in the database already. My thinking led me to a cascading process of 'try this, if not then try this' etc. using a CASE in the join.

However, it's not stopping at the first condition that's met and just returns everything that meets any condition - resulting in the same record in the contacts master being joined on more than once and duplicated in the results in many cases.

Is there a way to improve the join or is there just a better way to achieve matching across these data sets?

```
SELECT       nc.email
            ,nc.firstname
            ,nc.lastname
            ,nc.company
            ,cm.id_code
            ,cm.sales_region

FROM        [sales].[new_contacts] nc

LEFT JOIN   [sales].[contact_master] cm
       ON   CASE when nc.email = cm.email AND nc.fullname = cm.fullname and nc.company = cm.company then 1
                 when nc.email = cm.email AND nc.fullname = cm.fullname then 1
                 when nc.email = cm.email then 1
                 when nc.fullname = cm.fullname then 1
                 else 0 END = 1
```

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the ON clause.

Comment: All of the conditions in your `CASE` expression evaluate to `1`. It will be impossible to tell which one is returning a `TRUE` under those circumstances. Assuming that is a typo, or oversimplification of your actual code, then actual code and sample data that demonstrates your issue will be needed in order lend assistance.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: You could abbreviate the `JOIN` to `ON nc.fullname = cm.fullname` and would get the same result.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output